# BillingService has leaked ServiceConnection

Tags: android

I have attempted to integrate the code in [Blundell's in-app purchasing example](http://blog.blundell-apps.com/simple-inapp-billing-payment/) into my own app and its nearly all working. I have made an activity called shop.java which has a set of buttons, one for each possible item that can be purchased in my app. If I click on one of the buttons then a test purchase ("android.test.purchased") is made and appears to be carried out successfully. The log output appears reassuring:

```
CONFIRM_NOTIFICATIONS Sync Response code: RESULT_OK
Transaction complete
Transaction status: PURCHASED
Item purchased is: android.test.purchased
Received action: com.android.vending.billing.RESPONSE_CODE
checkResponseCode got requestId: 4731640731226687265
checkResponseCode got responseCode: RESULT_OK
Received action: com.android.vending.billing.RESPONSE_CODE
checkResponseCode got requestId: 1172244708705759861
checkResponseCode got responseCode: RESULT_OK
Received action: com.android.vending.billing.RESPONSE_CODE
checkResponseCode got requestId: 2684438012578976155
checkResponseCode got responseCode: RESULT_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE
Key action: 4
clipservice: android.sec.clipboard.ClipboardExManager@41d443c0
Stopping Service
```

control is returned to shop.java. I now press the back button to return to my apps's main activity. I presume that the shop.java's onDestroy method is called, but now I get the following error:

```
Service com.mycompany.mygame.BillingService has leaked ServiceConnection com.mycompany.mygame.BillingService@41d25498 that was originally bound here
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** Just noticed that I get exactly the same error even if I don't attempt to purchase anything!

Answer (score 8):

When initializing the billing service, try to give it the application context instead of the activity context. Use:

```
getApplicationContext()
```

Comment: I had a different problem caused by probably the same thing. Thanks, this helped.

Comment: changed
unbindService(mServiceConn);
to
getApplicationContext().unbindService(mServiceConn);
in
onDestroy() 
and works perfectly now :) THX!